# Is there a way to import list of tags from google tag manager to a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I´ve been assigned the most boring task ever. I need to write the name of the tags and its firing rules in a spreadsheet. Since we have a lot of clients, there are lots of tags.

I was wondering if there is a way to automatize that?

I would need only the name of the tag and its firing rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about automatizing, but since Excel can use HTML you can open the developer tools in your browser (I'm using Chrome, but other browsers should offer something similiar), go to the "elements" tab (or wherever source code is displayed in the browser of your choice), search the table element with the class `CT_TABLE`, right-click "copy as HTML" (which in Chrome will copy the whole table with all data), open an Excel spreadsheet and paste from the clipboard.

Still a manual process but a quick one.

(Note, since Excel can open data from the web it should be possible to automate the process, but even locating the correct option in the menu took me longer than doing it by hand).

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate on what "CT_TABLE" is? I'm trying to follow your suggestion but have a disconnect between going to the Elements tab and searching for "CT_TABLE". Thanks.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, I hope this makes it a bit easier to follow.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was wondering what "CT_TABLE" is as I didn't see it anywhere on OP's.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an easy way to do it :

Go to your GTM account
- Click Admin > Export container > choose your default workspace > export the doc
- Use a Json to CSV online software to transform your doc into a CSV (such as https://json-csv.com/)
- Find on the downloaded CSV the column with your list of tags
- Enjoy your power

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to build a data structure that is easily copied into your spreadsheet.

The following grabs the tag name + rule name + rule description and adds it to a textarea at the bottom of the page. The textarea contains tab delimited data which can be pasted into your spreadsheet.

GTM does not use jQuery, so you have to load it from a CDN.

Go to the Container Draft > Overview screen and run this in your dev console:

```
var jQuery = document.createElement('script');
jQuery.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jQuery);
```

Wait a second for it to load then run:

```
var tags = [];
jQuery.each(jQuery('#ID-tagTable .CT_TABLE_ROW'), function(i,row){
    var name = jQuery(row).find('.ACTION-clickTag').html();
    var rule = jQuery(row).find('.ACTION-clickCondition').html();
    var info = jQuery(jQuery('#ID-conditionTable .ACTION-clickCondition:contains("' + rule + '")').parent().siblings('td')[0]).html();
    tags.push([name,rule,info].join('\t'));
});
jQuery('body').append('<textarea cols="100" rows="10">' + tags.join('\n') + '</textarea>');
```

At the bottom of the page you'll find a textarea containing your tsv data.